# Going through arrays with for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Given an array called `array`, loop through all of its elements and print them out.

I have tried to use the following code but it is giving me the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`:

```
for element in array:
   print(array[element])
```

I have found the article [Accessing the index in 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops) and I've tried to implement it like so:

```
for element, x in enumerate(array):
   print(array[element])
```

This still does not print what I was searching for.

Comment: Can you share some samples inputs?

Comment: @DanielHao Of course, for example I have even tried:  `for element, x in enumerate(array): print(x)`. This seems to work, but I do not comprehend the need for "enumerate" and two variables ("element" and "x") when I will only be using one in the end.

Comment: Try to think of `index, elements` of enumerate.... Because enumerate gives a tuple of `index, element`

Comment: You're already looping over the elements. Use `print(element)`. If you want to loop over the indices, use `for element in range(len(array))` or `for index, element in enumerate(array)` to get both the indices and elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using normal for loop if you only need the elements of the array:

```py
for element in array:
    print(element)
```

Using [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) if you need the element and the index:

```py
for index, element in enumerate(array):
    print(f"index {index} has element: {element}")
```